# how to change multiple UI elements on runtime

Tags: unity-game-engine, uielement, gui-toolkit, uibuilder

I have many elements on my UI. I want to change the entire UI color. Basically like a new "Skin" for my HUD/Menu in game.
What is the best way to do this?
In UIBuilder, I can select a selector class and change the color, and it applies to all elements. How can I do this in runtime?
I have looked into USS variables, but it doesn't look like I can edit those using C# on runtime.

Answer (score 0):

The easiest answer I see is creating a `UIManager` class and placing it in the scene.

Your UI Manager will have an instance, thus making it a Singleton, here is the code that should be inside your UIManager

```
using System.Collections;
using UnityEngine;
using UnityEngine.UI;

public class UIManager : MonoBehaviour
{
    public static Singleton Instance { get; private set; }
    public Color[] skinColours;
    private void Awake() 
    { 
        // If there is an instance, and it's not me, delete myself.
        
        if (Instance != null && Instance != this) 
        { 
            Destroy(this); 
        } 
        else 
        { 
            Instance = this; 
        } 
    }

    public void ReskinUI(int skinIndex)
    {
        // Repeat this for RawImages, Buttons etc.
        foreach (Image image in GameObject.FindObjectsOfType<Image>())
        {
            image.color = skinColours[skinIndex];
        }
    }
}
```

After your define your `UIManager`, you can use it in your code like this.

```
UIManager.Instance.ReskinUI(1);
```

The '1' there, corresponds to the skin index.

Let me know if this helps

Answer (score 0):

Not sure what you are placing on your UI but there are only two generally, raw images and images.

Step 1. Create a script to gather the images and/or raw images and store a link to them
Step 2. Change the colour on those images.
Step 3. Ensure other things can grab your code to change the colour

**Step 1:**

```
/// <summary>
/// Gets all the images attached
/// </summary>
private void GetAllImagesInChildren()
{
    allGraphics = new List<Graphic>();
    foreach (Transform child in transform)
    {
        var image = child.gameObject.GetComponent<Image>();
        if (image)
        {
            allGraphics.Add(image);
        }
        else
        {
            var rawImage = child.gameObject.GetComponent<RawImage>();
            if (rawImage)
            {
                allGraphics.Add(rawImage);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Image and Raw image are both 'Graphic' types and they have the color attribute. Next just use GetComponent. It's also good practice to **use GetComponent as little as needed** hence storing the value. If you are only using RawImages feel free to switch the order.

**Step 2:**

```
/// <summary>
/// All raw images and images.
/// </summary>
private List<Graphic> allGraphics;

// Start is called before the first frame update
void Awake()
{
    GetAllImagesInChildren();
}

/// <summary>
/// Sets the Color of all the UI elements attached
/// </summary>
/// <param name="newColor">New color</param>
public void SetUIColor(Color newColor)
{
    foreach(Graphic graphic in allGraphics)
    {
        graphic.color = newColor;
    }
}
```

Let's attach the method from step one into a new script, store graphics privately and call it on awake. Then because graphics is now private create a simple public method which just uses our stored values. You could easily overload this with Color32 just copy and paste the method with that.

**All together:**

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;
using UnityEngine.UI;

public class UIColourChanger : MonoBehaviour
{
    /// <summary>
    /// All raw images and images.
    /// </summary>
    private List<Graphic> allGraphics;

    // Start is called before the first frame update
    void Awake()
    {
        GetAllImagesInChildren();
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Sets the Color of all the UI elements attached
    /// </summary>
   /// <param name="newColor">New color</param>
    public void SetUIColor(Color newColor)
    {
        foreach(Graphic graphic in allGraphics)
        {
            graphic.color = newColor;
        }
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Gets all the images attached
    /// </summary>
    private void GetAllImagesInChildren()
    {
        allGraphics = new List<Graphic>();
        foreach (Transform child in transform)
        {
            var image = child.gameObject.GetComponent<Image>();
            if (image)
            {
                allGraphics.Add(image);
            }
            else
            {
                var rawImage = child.gameObject.GetComponent<RawImage>();
                if (rawImage)
                {
                   allGraphics.Add(rawImage);
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Then simply the children of the object attached to this script are stored. Then just add:

```
public UIColourChanger ColorChanger;
```

or

```
[SerializeField]
private UIColourChanger colorChanger
```

To any other script and drag in this one into it to gain access to that public method.